# Find $w^2$ and compute a quadratic equation satisfied by $w$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I'm given $$\zeta_7 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}} = \cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
and I know $$\sum_{k=0}^{6}\zeta_7^k=0 $$

I'm then given $$w=\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4$$
and that $\zeta_7^7 = 1$.

I'm asked to find $w^2$ and I found that that's $\zeta^2_7+2\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^4+2\zeta_7^5+2\zeta_7^6+\zeta_7^8$ so $w^2=\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^6-1$ and if we add w, we get $\zeta_7^0+\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^4+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^6-2\zeta_7^0-w$ and that, I think, is just $-2-w$

So, if $w^2=-2-w$ then $w^2+w+2=0$ and w solves it, so that's the quadratic, right?

Comment: No, your result for $w^2$ is wrong.  Once you find the correct result, the quadratic equation will become obvious.

Comment: I think I've fixed it but I still don't see it

Comment: Your second expression for $w^2$ is incorrect. To rewrite the first expression in more ocnvenient form, note that $\zeta_7^8 = \zeta_7$.

Comment: any chance I've managed now?

Comment: The final expression should contain only $w$ and not $\zeta$.  You are forgetting about $k=0$.  Consider adding $w$ to your expression for $w^2$.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting closer. My algebra seems to be struggling today. How's this?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler approach:
$$w^2=(\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4)^2=\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4+\zeta_7^8+2\zeta_7^3+2\zeta_7^5+2\zeta_7^6,$$
so
$$w^2+w=2\zeta_7^2+2\zeta_7^4+2\zeta_7^1+2\zeta_7^3+2\zeta_7^5+2\zeta_7^6=2(0-\zeta_7^0)=2(-1),$$
hence
$w^2+w+2=0$.